# Unwrap multiple <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've this code :

```html
<strong>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
 </strong>
```

What I want to do is to unwrap all `<li>` from `<strong>`. At the end I want to have something like this :

```
<li>Hello</li>
<li>World</li>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: <li> must be inside <ul> however for "delete" tag in html you have to use JS

Comment: This is not a question. What have you tried? What have you done?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Using [unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) for this would be easier.

```js
$('li').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
 </strong>
```

As `li`'s must be in `ul` or `ol`. You can use alt way like

```
$('strong').replaceWith('ul');
```

Refere [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unwrap()`:

```js
$('strong').children().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
 </strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .unwrap() method removes the element's parent.

Try this code :

```
  var tag = $( "li" );
      if ( tag.parent().is( "strong" ) ) {
        tag.unwrap();
      }
```

HTML :

```
<strong>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
 </strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").unwrap();
})
```